# SMTPSenderRefused at /password-reset/ Authentication Required

Tags: python, django, smtp, gmail

I am adding password reset feature in my Django app, here is the code in `settings.py`

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASSWORD')
```

if I replace last two lines with:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@here.com'  # this
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'passwordOfEmailHere'  # this
```

this one works fine, this is the error I get when I use environment variables:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/password-reset/

Django Version: 2.2.7
Python Version: 3.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blogApp',
 'users.apps.UsersConfig',
 'crispy_forms']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\pytuts\Desktop\prac.py\django-proj\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\pytuts\Desktop\prac.py\django-proj\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\pytuts\Desktop\prac.py\django-proj\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\pytuts\Desktop\prac.py\django-proj\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\pytuts\Desktop\prac.py\django-proj\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\pytuts\Desktop\prac.py\django-proj\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\pytuts\Desktop\prac.py\django-proj\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py" in dispatch
  220.         return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\pytuts\Desktop\prac.py\django-proj\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  97.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\pytuts\Desktop\prac.py\django-proj\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  142.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "C:\Users\pytuts\Desktop\prac.py\django-proj\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py" in form_valid
  233.         form.save(**opts)

File "C:\Users\pytuts\Desktop\prac.py\django-proj\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py" in save
  295.                 email, html_email_template_name=html_email_template_name,

File "C:\Users\pytuts\Desktop\prac.py\django-proj\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py" in send_mail
  250.         email_message.send()

File "C:\Users\pytuts\Desktop\prac.py\django-proj\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py" in send
  291.         return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])

File "C:\Users\pytuts\Desktop\prac.py\django-proj\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py" in send_messages
  110.                 sent = self._send(message)

File "C:\Users\pytuts\Desktop\prac.py\django-proj\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py" in _send
  126.             self.connection.sendmail(from_email, recipients, message.as_bytes(linesep='\r\n'))

File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\Lib\smtplib.py" in sendmail
  867.             raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)

Exception Type: SMTPSenderRefused at /password-reset/
Exception Value: (530, b'5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError p26sm10496085lfh.64 - gsmtp', 'webmaster@localhost')
```

it looks like there is a problem with my environment variables. I added those environment variables as well:

[image]

I did all possible things to solve it, what is wrong? can you help me?

thank you

Comment: Use `os.environ['EMAIL_USER']` and `os.environ['EMAIL_PASSWORD']` - that way you'll get an error when the environment variables are missing. I don't know the best way to set environment variables on Windows, but [this suggests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/#the-django-admin-utility) you can use `SET EMAIL_HOST_USER=abc@example.com` in the command prompt before running `manage.py runserver`.

Comment: looks like it returned `None` from environment variables

Answer (score 0):

After creating your environment variables properly, you can simply **Restart** your computer. (This solution worked on Windows 7!)